# Gradle not found dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

There is no commons-lang.jar in External Libraries and i can't use StringUtils in my program. what i missing?

gradle version: 2.4

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gradle tool window try to press Refresh all Gradle projects button.

Here is more info about this window: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/gradle-tool-window.html

Comment: You can't do it in command line. Your gradle-file is perfectly ok and your project will compile via command line(gradlew ...). But Idea at this moment doesn't know about latest changes in build file. So you should refresh. Also you could open and close Idea - it should refresh project on the start